Send email from Twillo SenGrid and bring the response from webhook using C# code to know delivery or bounced status of email
I am using SendGrid C# code to send the emails, i was successfully sent the emails but in response i am not getting delivery status. If i send mail to wrong email address also, it is giving success response i am not getting bounce status response. Then i did some R&D how to get the delivery status, then i came to know about Webhook. I am new to Webhook i created a webhook URL in keen webiste and pasted in SendGrid webook events.
my normal Sendgrid email C# code
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY", "xxxxx");
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("xxx@xx.com", "CAP");
            var subject = "Testing email from Sendgrid";
            var to = new EmailAddress("abcdef@gmail.com", "Good User");
            var plainTextContent = "Hello, ";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>Congratulations! you have got the email</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            msg.SetBypassBounceManagement(true);
            msg.TrackingSettings = new TrackingSettings()
            {
                ClickTracking = new ClickTracking()
                {
                    Enable = true,
                    EnableText = false
                },
                OpenTracking = new OpenTracking()
                {
                    Enable = true,
                    SubstitutionTag = "%open-track%"
                },
                SubscriptionTracking = new SubscriptionTracking()
                {
                    Enable = false
                }
            };

            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);

But i don't know how to get the delivery status in response after sending email. Any one please help on this.

Pay $12 a month and you get to use their email activity api, or you will have to create another microservice and host a few apis where sendgrid provides a webhook for you to configure so that if any email is sent, it will automatically call your api. So you are looking at creating a new project with authentication and creating a controller and then going on sendgrid and entering the url of your new project, its lots of work
